# Bind size of ObservableList in Android Databinding

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin

How can I bind the size of an `ObservableList` in my view?
I´m using the databinding library with an `ObservableList` in my android app like this:

```
// ViewModel
class ViewModel {
    ...
    public final ObservableList<Item> items = new ObservableList<>()
    ...
}
```

and my View

```
// View
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable name="viewmodel" type="com.myapp.ViewModel" />
    </data>

    <TextView
        ...
        android:text="@{viewmodel.items.???}"
    />
</layout>
```

In the views `TextView` I want to show the size of the items-list. I tried to use `android:text="viewmodel.items.size` or `viewmodel.items.size()` but that doesn´t work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of Dany Minassians answer I found the following 2 solutions:

## Direct size() method

The usage of `items.size()` works. The problem is, that it returns an Integer and thus has to be converted into a String for the `android:text` element. This can be done with the `String.valueOf()` method.

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable name="viewmodel" type="com.myapp.ViewModel" />
    </data>

    <TextView
        ...
        android:text="@{String.valueOf(viewmodel.items.size())}"
    />
</layout>
```

## Using a helper method

The viewmodel can define a method like `sizeOfList(List list)` which can be used int the view like this:

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable name="viewmodel" type="com.myapp.ViewModel" />
    </data>

    <TextView
        ...
        android:text="@{String.valueOf(viewmodel.sizeOfList(viewmodel.items))}"
    />
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**INCORRECT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <data>
   <variable name="viewmodel" type="com.myapp.ViewModel "/>
</data>
<LinearLayout
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@{viewmodel.items::size()}"/>
</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

*I think you just forgot the @{ :: } ... 
try it like this because an ObservableList inherits the size() function from List according to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableList.html
and according to 
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#method_references 
to reference a method you need to use "::"*

**CORRECT ANSWER HERE AND STATED MORE CLEARLY BELOW **

If that doesnt work ... create a method in your model getListSize() and return size of the list using @{viewmodel::getListSize()} !

Comment: Thanks for your hint but `@{::}` is not the anwer. The :: binds methods for execution on events like "onClick". Nevertheless the `@{viewmodel.getListSize()} approach works (But one has to use "." instead of "::").